# Easy formatting in Python and pandas: Unknown format codes

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, format

Why is the python formatting giving me this error:

```
>>> type(df['rMeanPSFMag'])
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Convert the format of the rMeanPSFMag column::

```
>>> df['rMeanPSFMag'] = df['rMeanPSFMag'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
>>> type(df['rMeanPSFMag'])
pandas.core.series.Series

>>> df['rMeanPSFMag'] = df['rMeanPSFMag'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)
```

I then get a ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'

Comment: You want convert again float, but already converted column to string, so raise error. Need use code only once.

Comment: Okay, great. So, if I just want to keep the varilable as a float, but format it to e.g. 8 charaters, with 3 dps, how do I do that??

Comment: Do you think `df['rMeanPSFMag'] = df['rMeanPSFMag'].round(3)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected, because column have string values, so if convert again from `float` it raise error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rMeanPSFMag':[10.10235, 45.45871]})

print(df['rMeanPSFMag'].apply(type))
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
Name: rMeanPSFMag, dtype: object

#convert floats to strings with 3 decimals
df['rMeanPSFMag'] = df['rMeanPSFMag'].map('{:,.3f}'.format)

print(df)
  rMeanPSFMag
0      10.102
1      45.459

print(df['rMeanPSFMag'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
Name: rMeanPSFMag, dtype: object
```

If want float to `3 decimal`s use [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['rMeanPSFMag'] = df['rMeanPSFMag'].round(3)
print (df)

   rMeanPSFMag
0       10.102
1       45.459

print(df['rMeanPSFMag'].apply(type))
0    <class 'float'>
1    <class 'float'>
Name: rMeanPSFMag, dtype: object
```

Another solution is multiple by `1000`, convert to `integer`s and divide by `1000`:

```
df['rMeanPSFMag'] = df['rMeanPSFMag'].mul(1000).astype(int).div(1000)
print (df)

   rMeanPSFMag
0       10.102
1       45.458
```